# Error in restoring backup of database

Tags: c#, smo, database-restore

I know it may seem a duplicate question but previous questions could not solve my problem.
I used this code to restore the backup that I have created.

```
public string conrestore = "Data Source=.;Integrated Security=True";

private void btn_restore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conrestore))
        {
            ServerConnection srvconn = new ServerConnection(con);


            Server srvr = new Server(srvconn);

            if (srvr != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    Restore restoredb = new Restore();

                    restoredb.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;

                    restoredb.Database = "3LStoreDB";

                    OpenFileDialog openfd = new OpenFileDialog();

                    openfd.Filter = "Backup File (*.Bak)|*.Bak";

                    Nullable<bool> result = Convert.ToBoolean(openfd.ShowDialog());

                    if (result == true)
                    {
                        BackupDeviceItem bkDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(openfd.FileName, DeviceType.File);

                        restoredb.Devices.Add(bkDevice);

                        restoredb.ReplaceDatabase = true;

                        restoredb.SqlRestore(srvr);

                        MessageBox.Show("Restored successfully.");

                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex) 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It works properly till the line

```
restoredb.SqlRestore(srvr);
```

And it shows error `Restore failed for server 'Server Name'`

I don't know what's wrong with this code and I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's amazing and I don't know why this happened. But I Logged Off windows and again Logged in and now it works properly.